# Getting table of daily temperatures for host of cities using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm not experienced in using Google Earth Engine (GEE), so I've been beating my head against the wall for the past week trying to figure out how to do this. I am trying to export a table with daily average temperatures for cities in 3 select states, from Jan 1, 2018 to Dec 31, 2018. I have been able to get annual averages for each city - but what I really want is a daily average for each city. How should I think about this problem? Should I write a loop? The link to my code is: [click here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ae73d83044244229cb655bf4a75a47f)

```js
var gridmet: ImageCollection "GRIDMET: University of Idaho Gridded Surface Meteorological Dataset"

var prism18 = prism.filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31').select('tmean');

var gridmet18 = gridmet.filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31').select('tmmx','tmmn','pr');

var cityMean = gridmet18.reduceRegions(
{
  'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
  'scale': 4000,
  'collection': cities,
});
```

The asset 'cities' was created in ArcGIS. It contains city boundaries for the states of California, New York and Texas. A lot of the other things that I have tried so far have been commented out.

Comment: Please add a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck into the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the image collection, which contain the daily temperatures. Then you can reduceRegions and every feature will then contain properties for the mean of the pixels inside your defined area.

```
var dailyAverage = gridmet18.map(function(image){
  var time = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  var cityMeans = image.reduceRegions({
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
    'scale': 4000,
    'collection': cities,
  }).map(function(feat){
    return ee.Feature(feat).set('Date', time);
  });
  return cityMeans;
}).flatten();

print(dailyAverage)
```

You will probably need to export the collection to your assets (or drive), as it will run out of computation otherwise (due to GEE limits).

```
Export.table.toAsset(dailyAverage, 'exportedToAsset', 'exportedToAsset')
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I am really grateful to you. I was able to export the table to my Google Drive. I definitely wouldn't have been able to figure out the rest of the code on my own. I don't know who you are, but may the gods smile down upon you fondly.